# html input value javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
             <input class="count offer-count" type="number" value="1">
```

когда тип инпута даем number там появиться две стрелки один вниз один верх как можно давать класс либо айди на стрелки чтобы в js реализовать схему при каждом щелчке на стрелку в innerhtml прибавить либо убавить число

Comment: Вроде как никак. Придётся своё кастомное реализовывать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно программно вычислить где находятся кнопки увеличения/уменьшения числа и сделать на JS реализацию клика на эту область и менять число в инпуте. Однако это, я считаю, чрезмерно.

Вместо этого предлагаю воспользоваться методами **[stepDown()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_number_stepdown.asp)** и **[stepUp()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_number_stepup.asp)**, а дефолтные кнопки упрвления скрыть через *CSS*

```js
let result = document.getElementById('result');
let numberInput = document.getElementById('input');
numberInput.addEventListener('input', renderNumberInResult);

function stepUp() {
    numberInput.stepUp();
    renderNumberInResult();
}

function stepDown() {  
    numberInput.stepDown(); 
    renderNumberInResult();
}

function renderNumberInResult() {
    result.innerHTML = numberInput.value;
}

renderNumberInResult();
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<input id=input  class="count offer-count" type=number value="1">
<button onclick="stepUp()">+</button>
<button onclick="stepDown()">-</button> 

<div id="result">result</div>
```